# How and where to store user settings per session?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'd like to store some user choices per session, but have no idea where and how. To keep the problem as simple as possible:

- Lets say we have two links in the header: EN and FR (for language selecting purposes)
- When a user clicks on one of them we should be able to store somewhere the selected option
- Later on the site we should be able to access the selected option to take further steps to... translate some texts

So the question remains: Where and how to store the chosen language, and how to access it from anywhere on server side?

Comment: There is no single answer to this. This is a core design decision to be made by the designer of your application (probably you?), and not something we can answer for you.

Comment: Some common options are: Storing session data in a database, on the filesystem, or in memory. In some cases, it can make sense to store such data in secure, encrypted cookies, or even embedded in the URL (in plaintext). Each method has pros and cons, and choosing one depends on which characteristics are important for you and your application.

Comment: Well, you are almost right. I can create cookies no problem, but I can not find any solution where to access them on server side from my pieces or widgets. On the other hand I'm working on 'embedding it in the URL' but if I have many different settings to store this isn't a solution. Sessions are stored in the database but I don't find anything in the documentation about accessing it, changing it or anything.

Comment: If your goal is to translate text you should check out the apostrophe-workflow module which already addresses this.

Comment: Workflow is a little bit complicated (for our clients). We already made a brand new translation component. However the example was only an illustration of what we needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most complete answer but you can see an illustrated example of writing and reading sessions The Apostrophe Way in the `apostrophe-personas` module

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-personas/blob/master/index.js